# How do I use Unity to inject dependancies into ValidationFilters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, unity-container

I know how to inject dependencies into Action Filters, but I cannot figure out how to do the same with Validation Filters. Is there the equivalent of an ActionInvoker I can tap into?